# SQL - how to read MSDASQL Provider options

Tags: vb.net

I need to write a tool in vb.net that check if Provider Options(Dynamic parameter, Nested queries...) in SQL Server Management Studio, Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers > MSDASQL are true or not.

Is it possible use a query or something else?

[Provider Options](http://community.spiceworks.com/images/how_to_steps/0000/5912/030_msdasql_provider_options_plus_background.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a registry key for that: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\"Instance name"\Providers\MSDASQL

Thank you anyway!